# Scope dates in Ruby: Upcoming jobs which are 'due' between now and seven days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time, scope

I'm trying to scope all 'jobs' between now and it's 'due' date if that date is upcoming in the next seven days.

I know how to scope based on created_at - but not sure how to go about specific dates.

This is far as I've gotten. But I'm not sure where to stick due. The following of course, does not work.

```
def self.due_soon # in next 7 days
   where(Time.now-due.7.days)
end
```

Or is this a better approach:

```
def self.due_soon 
    where(':due < ?', Time.now-7.days)
end
```

And similarly, how would you go about scoping for a 'job' that is past due?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The solution lives [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions):

```
scope :due_soon, lambda { where(:created_at => (Time.now - 7.days)..Time.now) }
```

Comment: Ended up going with scope :due_soon, lambda { where('due <= ? and due >= now()', 7.days.from_now)